# jQuery Toggle - any way to know which (hide or show) is being applied?

Tags: jquery

I'm working in Adobe AIR, and I have a list of divs that show expanded information for each list item in a hidden div on a click - like so:

```
$(this).click(function(){
 $(this).next('div.info').toggle();
});
```

This extends the height of the whole app, so eventually, if the user were to expand all of the divs, there'd be a scrollbar on the side.  To get around this, I want to adjust the height of the window (either growing or shrinking, depending).  I have all of the code working, except I can't figure out how to get inside the .toggle function to find out which effect (hide or show) is going to be applied.  Setting my if() statement to key on the end-state of the info div doesn't work, because it assesses the div immediately on the click.

Is there any way to know which .toggle is being applied in jQuery so I can use that state change to apply my other changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After the toggle finishes, you can know which div was toggled:

```
var visible = $(this).next('div.info').toggle().is(":visible");
if(visible){
  alert("Hey! I've just showed up here!");
}
```

That way you'll know if the recent toggle operation showed the div or not.

Comment: This will not work since .is('visible') matches tags *named* "visible". You need to use the ':visible' CSS pseudo-selector instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can test this with:

```
if ($(selector).is(':visible')) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.class_name').click(function (event)
{
    triggerHideShow('#id_name'); // autodetect    
});

function triggerHideShow(id)
{
    if ($(id).is(':visible'))
    {
        $(id).hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $(id).show();
    }
}
```